# How to print "Processing..." multiple times while the subprocess popen communicate is still running

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, popen

How to print "Processing..." multiple times while the subprocess popen communicate is still running.

```
p =  Popen(abc, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,shell=False)
while p.poll() is None:
    print("Running")
output, error = p.communicate()
```

Here, my cmd command is stored in the abc variable, and the command requires an Enter at the end of it's execution to close the cmd, that's why and also for getting the output from the command, I am using p.communicate() here. I just want to continously print "Processing..." multiple times while the subprocess popen communicate is still running.

Answer (score 0):

I think the smartest way to do it would be to use another thread. Here's a sample of what I mean.

```py
import threading
import time


def long_task():
    time.sleep(3)
    return "result", 0


def helper():
    global output
    global exit_code
    output, exit_code = long_task()


output: str
exit_code: int

thread = threading.Thread(target=helper)
thread.start()

while thread.is_alive():
    print("Processing...")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Here I create a new thread, that calls the helper method, which assigns values to the variables and by calling the long_task, which would be p.communicate in your case. Then after starting the thread, while it's alive (meaning the target function hasn't finished), print "Processing..." every second.

Hope this helped.